# error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dextras 3dcore 3drender 3dinput

Tags: qt

I m using Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed Qt6 using Qt installer and I opened an example to run(simple-cpp). I m getting the following error:

```
:-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dextras 3dcore 3drender 3dinput
```

Where does the QtCreator tries to find the modules? I have these modules in the installation folder, how to give the path to those modules?

Comment: what build system is used in the project? CMake or QMake?

Comment: qmake build system.

Comment: please provide your .pro file source codes, is it a simple Qt project or your own project?

Comment: I m using the examples provided by the Qt. Please look [here](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/tree/dev/examples/qt3d/simple-cpp) for the one I m looking into.